# Embedded Keycloak server hostname variable configuration

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

We use Keycloak + Spring boot + Keycloakify to build an Authorization server for our microservices.
We use Embedded Keycloak with Spring boot to customize login and registration after this, we build Keycloakify themes and one Docker container with everything.

We are facing an issue after deploying the docker container to AWS Fargate.
I use a target group and application load balancer with the listener on the 443 port to route requests to the AWS Fargate container.

After I go to the admin login page and see infinite spinner and in the browser console an error message:

```
Refused to frame 'http://dev-sso.my-domain.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".
```

I saw some posts about that. And that said to set KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME variable. But after setting this variable as an environment variable in the container with my domain nothing changed.

My question is, how to configure the Keycloak hostname on the embedded Keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do this.

But what I have done.
My Keycloak Fargate Container connects to the AWS RDS, and I done a connection to the database and execute the SQL script below.

```
INSERT INTO REALM_ATTRIBUTE (REALM_ID, VALUE, NAME )
VALUES ('<master_realm_id>', 'https://dev-sso.my-domain.com', 'frontendUrl');
```

To get the master realm id, just go to the REALM table and get it from here.